# Would my UK fiancé have to get a visa for the US for more than a month?

Tags: usa, visa, uk-citizens

I have a fiancé who is a UK resident and would like to visit me for just over a month. Would he need to get a visa if he is to stay that long?

Comment: His residence in the UK is irrelevant (wasn't always the case, but is now). What is his nationality? Are you planning on getting married in the U.S. Are you a U.S. citizen?

Answer (score -1):

Yes. The US allows UK citizens to use the “[Visa Waiver Program](https://rapidvisa.com/visa-waiver-program-countries/),” but you still need an ESTA before you can travel. You can get a single ESTA if you’re traveling alone, or you can apply as part of a group.

Comment: The question doesn't say the fiance is a UK citizen.